# Vue: SVG element will not scale inside when rendered from a template

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, svg, scaling

So, *outside of Vue.js*, I can use the following tricks to ensure my SVG scales to fit within the div inside of it:

- declare a `viewbox` attribute on the parent `svg` element
- omit a `height` attribute on the parent `svg` element
- set the `width` attribute to `100%` on the parent `svg` element

Then, when the div resizes, the SVG scales along with it.

But *inside of Vue.js*, when I do the exact same thing, but inside of a component rendered by Vue, it stays a constant static size (defined in pixels by the `viewbox` dimensions).

However, I can overcome this obstacle by forcing the DOM to reevaluate/re-render the SVG calling this code:

```
parentSvgDiv.innerHTML = parentSvgDiv.innerHTML;
```

Only, that seems extremely hackish, especially for production code. So, **is there any way to have an SVG rendered by Vue also be capable of filling the size of its parent div container?**

### SSCCE 1: Outside of Vue.js (SVG scaling works)

```js
var d = document.querySelector('.my-div');
var i, t;

function grow() {
  if (d.style.width === '100px') {
    t = 0;
    i = setInterval(function() {
      if (t >= 20) {
        clearInterval(i);
      }
      d.style.width = (100 + t++ * 20) + 'px';
    }, 50);
  }
}

function shrink() {
  if (d.style.width === '500px') {
    t = 20;
    i = setInterval(function() {
      if (t <= 0) {
        clearInterval(i);
      }
      d.style.width = (100 + t-- * 20) + 'px';
    }, 50);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="grow()">Grow</button>
<button onclick="shrink()">Shrink</button>
<div class="my-div" style="height: 500px; width: 100px;">
  <svg width="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100">
    <polygon stroke-width="3" stroke="#000000" fill="none" points="50,0 62,38 100,50 62,62 50,100 38,62 0,50 38,38"></polygon>
  </svg>
</div>
```

### SSCCE 2: Inside of Vue.js (SVG scaling does not work)

```js
Vue.component('star-svg', {
  template: `
    <div class="my-div" style="height: 500px; width: 100px;">
      <svg width="100%" viewbox="0 0 100 100" >
        <polygon stroke-width="3" stroke="#000000" fill="none" points="50,0 62,38 100,50 62,62 50,100 38,62 0,50 38,38"></polygon>
      </svg>
    </div>  
  `
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {}
});

var d = document.querySelector('.my-div');
var i, t;

function grow() {
  if (d.style.width === '100px') {
    t = 0;
    i = setInterval(function() {
      if (t >= 20) {
        clearInterval(i);
      }
      d.style.width = (100 + t++ * 20) + 'px';
    }, 50);
  }
}

function shrink() {
  if (d.style.width === '500px') {
    t = 20;
    i = setInterval(function() {
      if (t <= 0) {
        clearInterval(i);
      }
      d.style.width = (100 + t-- * 20) + 'px';
    }, 50);
  }
}

function fix() {
  d.innerHTML = d.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.js"></script>
<button onclick="grow()">Grow</button>
<button onclick="shrink()">Shrink</button>
<button onclick="fix()">Fix Scaling Issue</button>
<div id="app">
  <star-svg></star-svg>
</div>
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45274554 You need to use `viewBox`, not `viewbox`.

Comment: Holy cow. I didn't think it would be that easy. And it is. That is just such a hard thing to Google. Thanks @skirtle and thanks SO.